# Why can't I initialize or evaluate my variable in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I must be misunderstanding how TF works. Here's some code I found. I want to evaluate "mask" and then print it

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])

mask = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(a, dtype=tf.int32))
sess.run(mask.initializer())
print(mask.eval())
```

It gives me: 'Operation' object is not callable. If I delete the sess.run line, it gives me "attempting to use uninitialized value." What's the problem?

Comment: change this statement `sess.run(mask.initializer())` to `sess.run(mask.initializer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this statement `sess.run(mask.initializer())` to `sess.run(mask.initializer)`

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])

mask = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(a, dtype=tf.int32))
sess.run(mask.initializer)
print(mask.eval())
```